# how to enable devise helper methods in rails controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i've seen the other posts on this topic, I understand that devise helper methods need to be enabled by either adding them to the test_helper or spec_helper files, but that doesn't seem to be working.

what else should I be looking at to solve this ?

my rspec erro,

```
Failures:

  1) LunchersController GET root renders index view for non-logged in users
     Failure/Error: get :index, {}
     NoMethodError:
       Could not render layout: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/lunchers_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

my spec_helper relevant lines

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller

end
```

i don't have a test/ but I've created one and added a test_helper to see if including the below helps, which it doesn't.

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.1.0"

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem "haml", "~> 4.0.4"
gem "angularjs-rails", "~> 1.2.7"
gem "zeus", "~> 0.13.3"
gem "pg", "~> 0.17.1"
gem "devise"
gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-twitter"
gem "uuidtools"
gem "quiet_assets", "~> 1.0.2"
gem "thin", "~> 1.6.1"
gem "jader", "~> 0.0.8"
gem "ngmin-rails", "~> 0.4.0"
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem "twitter"

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14.1"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem "mocha", "~> 1.0.0"
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 1.2.0"
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-debugger'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a file (say devise.rb) inside `spec/support` folder with the content you mentioned for spec_helper?

Comment: @AlexP that does not work

Comment: Does `sign_in` method work in your controller tests? Let's say if you created a user with `factory_girl` and then `sign_in(@user)`.

Comment: i took the nuclear option on this one and downgraded devise to 3.0.0 and everything seems to be working so far.